# (Un)Decidability of the root existence problem for functions with bounded domain

Tags: decidability, lo.logic

The problem whether a real function $f$ has a root or not is undecidable, given that $f$ is from a class of functions including polynomials and the sine function (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321856). Usually, undecidability is proved by using a periodic function like sin to encode integer problems. Is there anything known about undecidability of the root existence problem for some "reasonable" class of functions with *bounded domains*, such as from a bounded $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: As mentioned in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109814 , the real field expanded with all analytic functions on a bounded domain is an o-minimal structure. However, I’m not aware of any results on the decidability of its reducts to a finite language (note that decidability of an o-minimal structure is equivalent to decidability of the root existence problem for its definable functions). Decidability of the real field with exponentiation is a notorious open problem related to Schanuel’s conjecture.

Comment: Also, asking the functions to have bounded domain does not make much of a difference per se. A “reasonable” class of functions on, say, $(0,1)^m$ can be made into a “reasonable” class of functions on $\mathbb R^m$, and vice versa, by composing with a “reasonable” homeomorphism of $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$, such as $1/(1-x)-1/x$.

Comment: Emil: right, thank you. What I have in mind is in fact compact domains (typically, finite unions of cubes), my formulation was not very good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose there is an algorithm that decides whether a function $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ has a root. Then one can also compute a root of $f$ if $f$ has one.

One can see this using a standard bi-partition argument:
Cover $\Omega$ with finitely many balls of radius $1$. This is possible since the closure of $\Omega$ is compact. Then using the algorithm we can find a ball that contains a root of $f$.
Then we cover this ball with balls of radius $2^{-1}$ and again find a smaller ball which contains a root...

Iterating this process yield a sequence converging to a root of $f$ with rate $2^{-n}$ or in other words a Cauchy-real representation for a root.

Now, finding a root for a function implies Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

To see that let $\Omega$ be bounded and closed and $g\colon \Omega \to \Omega$ continuous. $g$ has a fixed-point at any root of the function $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x):= \lvert g(x) - x\rvert$.

For Brouwers fixed point theorem it is known that there is no algorithm to find solutions, see for instance [Computable counter-examples to the Brouwer fixed-point theorem, Petrus H. Potgieter](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3199).

Thus, we can conclude that there is no algorithm which decides whether a function has a root.

Comment: The questions asks for an algorithm *deciding* whether or not the function has a root, not an algorithm for *finding* a root. So you need an extra step to show that deciding whether there is a solution in $\Omega$ also allows you to compute one. I think that can be done but it would be nice to include here.

Comment: @François thank you, I missed that point.

Comment: This is really beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is continuous (and therefore uniformly continuous) on a compact domain $K \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ (and this is effective in the sense that given $\epsilon > 0$ you can construct $\delta > 0$ such that
$\|x - y\| < \delta$ implies $\|f(x) - f(y)\| < \epsilon$.  Then if $f(x) = 0$ has no solution in $K$ you can prove that fact: take $\epsilon > 0$ small enough, take $\delta$ as above, cover $K$ with finitely many open balls of radius $\delta$, and compute the values of $f$ at the centres of these balls with sufficient precision to show they all have norm $> \epsilon$.

Comment: Robert: thank you. However, in this way you can only prove the non-existence of a root (if it doesn't exists). 

Comment: Peter: Yes, I know.  I don't think there is any way in general to prove the existence of a root if it does exist.